i cant able to host in web browser in EC2 instance
When I click on the public IP or private IP of my EC2 instance, I am consistently seeing the site can't be reached error. I encountered this issue when I tried to create an EC2 instance for the first time. Can anyone help identify the mistake I might have made? I want to create an EC2 instance and host it locally. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
my EC2 Instances page:

MY EC2 INSTANCE security page:


Where are you seeing this error? Does it happen when you put the IP address of the EC2 instance in your web browser? Please note that Amazon EC2 instances do not have web servers installed by default, so they will not respond to HTTP/S requests.

You will have to install web server Apache or Nginx first on the EC2 instance and also make sure you have added port 80 and 443 in security group inbound group, so that the instance can accept the traffic on these ports and work properly with the web server, then you will be able to see the default page of the installed web server.
Hope this helps you.
